# how to use `sudo` in build.jl of a package

Tags: julia

build.jl

```
run(`sudo -S mkdir test`)
```

when you run `Pkg.build("TestBuild")`, You will have no chance to input the passwd.

```
julia> Pkg.build("TestBuild")
INFO: Building TestBuild
[sudo] password for guo: 
==============================[ ERROR: TestBuild      ]==============================

LoadError: failed process: Process(`sudo -S mkdir test`, ProcessExited(1))
```

This demo package `TestBuild` is at [Github](https://github.com/zhmz90/TestBuild.jl).

how to use `sudo` in build.jl?

Answer (score 1):

```
run(`mkfifo /tmp/pwd-fifo`)
prompt = "sudo need your password, please run [read -s p && echo \$p > /tmp/pwd-fifo] in another shell.\n\
"
sudo = @async run(`bash -c "sudo -S -p '' touch /tmp/tx < /tmp/pwd-fifo"`)
print(prompt)
wait(sudo)
```

The above code provided by [KDr2](https://github.com/KDr2)